# React Form Hook with Autocomplete Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a `countries` array which contains `id` and `name`. Currently I am using a Material UI `Autocomplete` element and I have a react hook form. When I submit the form, I want to fetch the country Id. Currently it is posting the country name. Is there a way to post the ids instead of the names without going and fetching the id from the name.

```
   <Autocomplete
      className="form-item"
      options={countries}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          inputRef={register}
          label="Country"
          name="country"
          placeholder="Select a Country"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use react-hook-form's [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/v5/api/#Controller) and put the entire `Autocomplete` in the `as` prop. With this, when you submit the form you will get the entire object of the selected option.

**Note**: In react-hook-form version 6.x, the `onChange` [is removed](https://github.com/react-hook-form/documentation/pull/252), the as prop will take a function and you can obtain `onChange` as param.

[Working demo - v6](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-hook-form-get-id-version-6-s4zvw?file=/demo.js)

```js
    <Controller
        as={({ onChange }) => (
          <Autocomplete
            className="form-item"
            options={countries}
            onChange={(_, data) => onChange(data)}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
            renderInput={params => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Country"
                placeholder="Select a Country"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
                variant="outlined"
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
        name="country"
        control={control}
        defaultValue={{ label: "The Shawshank Redemption", id: "1994" }}
      />
```

**Note**: If you are using v5x then see demo and code snippet below.

[Working demo - v5](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-hook-form-get-id-q13c0?file=/demo.js)

```js
   <Controller
        as={
          <Autocomplete
            className="form-item"
            options={countries}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
            renderInput={params => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Country"
                placeholder="Select a Country"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
                variant="outlined"
              />
            )}
          />
        }
        name="country"
        control={control}
        onChange={([, data]) => data}
        defaultValue={{ label: "The Shawshank Redemption", id: "1994" }}
      />
```

**Edit**: based on comment
You can use [setValue](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#setValue) to set default values based on an api.

code snippet:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { // fake api
      setValue(
        "country",
        { label: "hi The Godfather", id: "1972" },
        { shouldDirty: true }
      );
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
```

Demo v6 above is updated.

Also see [official demo of setValue usage here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-setvalue-wjplb?file=/src/index.jsx)

Comment: Thanks! submit is working fine. Do you have any idea how I can populate the form initially? I am currently using reset() function. When I fetch the user profile I want to set the value the object that I receive

Comment: as your original qn is all sorted, please see if you can consider to upvote and accept the answer .. thanks.

Comment: One last issue, whenever I click on submit, the values of the Autocomplete is changing back to the original value. Although it is posting the correct object. I need to refresh to see the updated value. But why on submit click the values are changing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplest way to create it, render your `Autocomplete` component inside Controller from react hook from, use `onChange` and `value` from the `render` function  to control the value

```js
<Controller
control={control}
name="type"
rules={{
  required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
}}
render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
  <Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    options={['field', 'select', 'multiple', 'date']}
    onChange={(event, values) => onChange(values)}
    value={value}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="type"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    )}
  />
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that there is not an 'easy' way to get the ids with the current setup.

However, you can hook into the `Autocomplete#onChange` event and use the `value` prop to take over the internal value state of the Autocomplete component. This results in having the value available in your component and use this to your advantage.

In the example below, the id will be available in the form data as `country-id`.

```
function CountryAutocomplete() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(); // `[]` for multiple

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Autocomplete
        className="form-item"
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, value) => setValue(value)}
        options={countries}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            inputRef={register}
            label="Country"
            name="country"
            placeholder="Select a Country"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true
            }}
            variant="outlined"
          />
        )}
      />
      <input value={value?.id} name="country-id" />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```